# Django error with the html links TypeError at / 'set' object is not reversible

Tags: django, templates, url, backend

Im learning Django right now , and i have start the html integrations so i have put all static pages into one app, everything was working , so i have 3 page Home/ SignUp/ Login , and im tryin to link all pages with others so this is what i did

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns =[
path('', views.index , name='index'),
path('SignUp', views.SignUp , name='signup'),
path('login', views.login, name='login'),
]
```

html code

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="nav-header">
                    <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle"><i></i></a>
                    <h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">My Personal Trainer<span> 
                     App</span></a></h1>
                    <!-- START #fh5co-menu-wrap -->
                    <nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">
                        <ul class="sf-menu" id="fh5co-primary-menu">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- <li><a href="trainer.html">About Us</a></li> -->
                            <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign Up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('base/index.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))



 def login(request):
    template= loader.get_template('base/login.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))


def SignUp(request):
    template= loader.get_template('base/signup.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request=request))
```

main urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
 path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
 path('coach/', include('coach.urls')),
 path('store/', include('store.urls')),
 path('', include('base.urls')),

]
```

IM GETTING this error when i try to access one of those pages:
TypeError at /
'set' object is not reversible
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
'set' object is not reversible

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiIlc.png)

thanks for your help and attention

Comment: can you share the main url code?

Comment: i've added on the main post urls  code

Comment: have you tried without the / in the url? I mean http://127.0.0.1:8000 only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have three apps:

```
 path('coach/', include('coach.urls')),
 path('store/', include('store.urls')),
 path('', include('base.urls')),
```

Please check each one of these apps `urls.py` to see **if you accidently put
`{ }` rather than `[ ]`.**

Comment: Thanks a lot , it was on stoore app i did what u told me and its work perfectly big up man